# Smart Wi-Fi Switch with No Ground

Tags: switches

I want to install some smart switches in an older home without ground wires.

I'd also prefer not having to purchase a "Smart Hub" as they seem to be going away and not necessary.

Note, I use Google, no Apple if that makes a difference.

Other than running a ground back to the panel (too expensive) is there a way to make this work?

I realize the smart switch must have some power to stay On so it can respond to Wi-Fi, etc.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't know the first thing about these switches, but I think it would be helpful if you shared the datasheet of the switch in question.

Comment: Many WiFi routers and Ethernet switches have no Earth connection (they use a two pin plug), so you need to be clear about what you want to connect. "Smart Hub" and "Smart switches" does not tell anyone what you are using.

Comment: The question *might* be about switches that would install in the wall box in place of a mechanical one; those would either need to send a small amount of current through the load even when "off" (which some loads may not like), have an extra return wire (*return*, not *ground*) or use batteries.  But from a *user* perspective these are all *off topic* here - only a very narrow question within the *design* of such a device would be on topic.

Comment: Yes, this is regarding replacing a wall box switch for a light in a room. There are many to choose from. Apparently this is Off Topic. So, an extra return wire? If there are 2 switches in the wall next to each other, could I just connect the Return of the Smart Switch to the "dumb" switch?

Comment: Get an electrician to give advice. It depends on your existing wiring (and it may not meet current standards).

Comment: related: https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2598/how-does-a-smart-switch-get-its-power/3122#3122

Comment: do you mean without a neutral?

Answer (score 3):

In mains electrical wiring, ground is a **safety shield**.  Current never flows on ground (except during a fault) and you never, never intentionally return current there. Never.

Mains electrical also has a "Neutral", which is analogous to electronics Vss or GND.

A smart switch needs to power itself at all times, so it can respond to requests.  It obtains power across two wires: **Neutral**, and **always-hot** aka supply aka line.  Your smart switch needs *Neutral*.

An old school steam switch does not need neutral, so it typically has two wires: always-hot aka supply aka line, and switched-hot aka lamp aka load.

If you look in the back of the junction box, you may find some white wires in a bundle. Or light blue in modern European installations, or God knows what in older world installations. You can add the smart switch's neutral wire to that bundle of white or light blue wires. Don't break up the bundle; they are not spares.

Not every switch box has neutral.  A few smart switches in the US tout themselves as "not needing neutral" -- however some of *those* do need safety ground, because what they're really doing is returning current via ground instead of the neutral they'd normally use. (didn't I just say never do that?  They got a waiver from Underwriter's Laboratories to do that thing.  The NFPA has told UL to knock it off.)

Yet other devices can power themselves by leaking current through the lamp.  This depends on either an incandescent bulb, or an LED which is designed to tolerate this.  Those leaker types do not need neutral nor ground.  If you use one with an LED *not* designed to tolerate this, either the LED will fail to work, catch fire, or glow at all times. (so will the incandescent, just not bright enough to see).   With this type, you can also install a resist-- wait, DO NOT hit Mouser's website and go order a resistor, anything you install in Mains wiring must be rated and approved for that use, and Leviton and a few other makers make listed capacitive/resitive based *products* for that purpose.  Just use those.

Comment: Please post a source regarding your comment about the UL dispute.

Comment: @bremen after 2 years a little tough, but there's this, reflecting the UL's tendency to bless this but NFPA's saying "enough". https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=301.0